# How to rotate sceen from kernel/console in android ?

Tags: console, orientation, android-kernel

I am trying to rotate screen (whole fb) from kernel. Due to some hardware changes my phone screen is coming in inverting mode. Where can I change in kernel for changing default screen orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate screen from kernel/console by

"service call window XX i32 X"

Ex:

service call window 61 i32 0 //rotate to normal

service call window 61 i32 1 //rotate clockwise

The 61 is on my device only, you should find out what is yours.

You can also rotate from PC by adb

Ex:

adb shell service call window 61 i32 0

Comment: This is exactly what I need. But... how do I determine the value I should use instead of 61?